# Returning workbook object from function

Tags: vba, excel

I'm using VBA w/ Excel 2010 and am trying to create (what seems like it should be) a simple function.  I want the function to receive a string argument and, if the string matches the name of an open workbook, return a reference to that workbook object; if no match is found it should return "#NAME?".  (The function also tries concatenating common file extensions to get a match, for user-friendliness.)

Here's what it looks like:

```
Function BookFromName(bookName As String) As Workbook

    Dim wb As Workbook

    For Each wb In Workbooks
        Select Case (wb.Name)
            Case bookName, _
                bookName & ".xls", _
                bookName & ".xlsx", _
                bookName & ".xlsm":
                Set BookFromName = wb
                Exit Function
         End Select
    Next

    MsgBox ("Workbook '" & bookName & "' is not open.")
    BookFromName = CVErr(xlErrName)
End Function
```

Right now I'm getting the error: *"Run-time error 438: Object doesn't support this property or method."*  From this line:

```
Set BookFromName = wb
```

I tried switching the return type to Variant or Object, but it doesn't change anything.

I also tried removing SET from the line (even though that doesn't seem correct to me), which changes the error to *"Run-time error 91: Object variable or With block variable not set."*

I scanned Google and StackExchange for a while, but I can't find any examples of a function returning a workbook object, and not just the name of a workbook.

---

Here is Veve's suggestion, which works fine, but I would prefer to pass references:

```
Function BookFromName(bookName As String) As Variant

    Dim wb As Workbook

    For Each wb In Workbooks
        Select Case (wb.Name)
            Case bookName, _
                bookName & ".xls", _
                bookName & ".xlsx", _
                bookName & ".xlsm":
                BookFromName = wb.Name
                Exit Function
        End Select
    Next
    MsgBox ("Workbook '" & bookName & "' is not open.")
    BookFromName = CVErr(xlErrName)
End Function
```

Comment: Can't you just return the workbook name and use it after the call to your function to do whatever you want with it?

Comment: That would get the job done, but I'm worried that I'm missing some nuance of VBA syntax for passing references.  Is my problem that I'm trying to treat VBA like .NET?

Comment: Does the function work if a workbook being searched for is open?

Comment: It always throws an error on the SET line.  If i put a MsgBox right above it, I can show the name of a matching workbook, but it'll still error on SET.

Comment: (I didn't mean to comment, but now I must use atleast 15 chars)

Comment: (1) if you start a comment, you can delete the lot and its OK.  You can also switch to a different page and your half-written comment will be lost. (2) I cannot duplicate your error with Excel 2003.  I will post my test code as an answer.  Can someone try it with a later version.  Is this a bug in Excel 2010 or is there something wrong or inconplete with Carl's installation.

Comment: My routine was a little more complicated that mememoremore's but not by much.  It appears the function works with Excel 2003 and 2007. Do you have a missing reference?  I have: "Visual Basic for Applications" and "Microsoft Excel 11.0 Object Library".

Comment: Carl, your original code is absolutely fine except for the LAST executable line in the function: you are effectively trying to assign a String to a Workbook Object variable--not good, this will error out, not the "Set BookFromName = wb". Something is not right here, obviously. Could you please show the calling sub as well?

Comment: `wb.name` is case sensitive (tried `?thisworkbook.name` and got capital letters and lower case), so "MyWB.xls" is different to "mywb.xls". Advise to use a `ucase` for wb.name, also `booName = Ucase(bookName)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very important is to know **how/where your function will be called**.

- When called **from Sheet cell(s)** then it can't return reference to Workbook *(see example BookFromName1)*
- When called from within other **VBA code** then it shouldn't use CVErr *(see example BookFromName2)*

*Note: using `Like` the workbook name extension can be omitted.*

HTH

```
' As 'User Defined Function' (functions that are called directly from worksheet cells)
Function BookFromName1(bookName As String) As Variant

    On Error Resume Next
    Dim tempWorkbook As Workbook
    Dim isOpen As Boolean
    Dim bookNameLike As String
    bookNameLike = LCase(bookName) & "*"
    For Each tempWorkbook In Workbooks
        If LCase(tempWorkbook.Name) Like bookNameLike Then
            isOpen = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    On Error GoTo 0

    If Not isOpen Then
        MsgBox ("Workbook '" & bookName & "' is not open.")

        ' return error #NAME? to the cell which called this formula
        BookFromName1 = CVErr(xlErrName)
    Else
        ' returns TRUE to the cell which called this formula
        BookFromName1 = True
    End If
End Function

' As common VBA function (used in another VBA code)
Function BookFromName2(bookName As String) As Workbook

    On Error Resume Next
    Dim tempWorkbook As Workbook
    Dim bookNameLike As String
    bookNameLike = LCase(bookName) & "*"
    For Each tempWorkbook In Workbooks
        If LCase(tempWorkbook.Name) Like bookNameLike Then
            Set BookFromName2 = tempWorkbook
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    On Error GoTo 0

    If BookFromName2 Is Nothing Then
        Dim errorMessage As String
        errorMessage = "Workbook '" & bookName & "' is not open."
        MsgBox errorMessage
        ' In this case (differently from UDF) you can't use CVErr
        ' but you could raise error if you wish.
        ' (Or outcomment Err.Raise and simply return Nothing.)
        Err.Raise vbObjectError + 513, "BookFromName2", errorMessage
    End If
End Function

Sub TestBookFromName2()
    Dim myBook As Workbook
    On Error GoTo errHandler
    ' Like is used to compere book names so the .xls, .xlsx etc. can be omitted
    Set myBook = BookFromName2("SomeBookNameHere")
    Exit Sub
errHandler:
    MsgBox Err.Description, vbExclamation
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest to use function like:

```
Function IsWbkOpen(ByVal sName As String) As Boolean
Dim extensions As Variant, retVal As Boolean, wbk As Workbook
Dim i As Integer

retVal = False
extensions = Array("", ".xls", ".xslx", ".xlsm")

On Error Resume Next 'ignore errors

For i = LBound(extensions) To UBound(extensions)
    Set wbk = Application.Workbooks(sName & extensions(i))
    If Not wbk Is Nothing Then retVal = True: Exit For
Next

IsWbkOpen = retVal

End Function
```

Then you'll be able to create procedure:

```
Sub Test()
Dim wbk As Workbook, wbkName As String

wbkName = "Workbook1"
If Not IsWbkOpen(wbkName) Then
    'call FileOpenDialog
End If

'proceed 

End Sub
```

Create objects inside function only when you sure that function can create object, unless it will return **Nothing** (which is unexpected, undesirable).

Below is function which opens Workbook by its full name. Of course, there is need to add Error handler.

```
Function CreateWbkFromName(ByVal sFullName As String) as Workbook

    If Dir(sFullName)<>"" Then
        Set CreateWbkFromName= Application.Workbooks.Open(sFullName)
    Else
        'here is a danger of Nothing
    End If
End Function
```

Cheers,
Maciej

Answer (score 1):

The code by Maciej Los is nice, I would use his.

To work, your code needs changing as follows (see code comments), I hope this helps you understand your code better.  Here's the results of calling it

```
? BookFromName(thisworkbook.Name).Name
Book1
? BookFromName("Not open") is nothing
True



Function BookFromName(bookName As String) As Workbook

    Dim wb As Workbook

    For Each wb In Workbooks
        Select Case (wb.Name)
            Case bookName   
                ' NOTE  NO ":" IS NEEDED as it is a "command break" character 
                '       wb.Name does not return the file extension only the filename.
                Set BookFromName = wb                           ' SET ADDED
                Exit Function
         End Select
    Next

    MsgBox ("Workbook '" & bookName & "' is not open.")
    Set BookFromName = Nothing                                
               ' ADD SET AND USE NOTHING
               ' CVErr(xlErrName) would only be used if you are calling from an excel cell.
               ' As this returns and object this function will not be used 
               ' from excel 
               ' In the calling function test for is nothing to find if a workbook was found
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

you didn't consider case sensitive, so try this instead :

```
Function BookFromName(bookName As String) As Workbook

Dim wb As Workbook
dim h$
bookName = Ucase (bookName)

For Each wb In Workbooks
        h = ucase (wb.name)
        if h = bookName & ".XLS" or h = bookName & ".XLSX" or h = bookName & ".XLSM" then 
            Set BookFromName = wb
            set wb = nothing
            Exit Function
        end if
Next wb

set wb = nothing
beep
MsgBox ("Workbook '" & bookName & "' is not open.")
'BookFromName = CVErr(xlErrName)
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried your first function **Function BookFromName(bookName As String) As Workbook** in Excel 2007 and it works fine. I run it like following, where I have BS.xlsm opening at the same time.

```
Function BookFromName(bookName As String) As Workbook

    Dim wb As Workbook

    For Each wb In Workbooks
        Select Case (wb.Name)
            Case bookName, _
                bookName & ".xls", _
                bookName & ".xlsx", _
                bookName & ".xlsm":
                Set BookFromName = wb
                Exit Function
         End Select
    Next

    MsgBox ("Workbook '" & bookName & "' is not open.")
    BookFromName = CVErr(xlErrName)
End Function


Sub main()
 Dim wb As Workbook
 set wb = BookFromName("BS")
 MsgBox wb.Name
End Sub
```

Alternatively, how about rewrite your function to pass parameters by reference

**Sub BookFromName(bookName As String, byref wb as workbook)**

whatever you assigned to wb variable in function BookFromName, it still exists after BookFromName function ended.